# How to display text in a pdf file?

Tags: c#, .net, itext

I am using c#.net and need for some data to be displayed in a .pdf file. I am able to do so by using a PdfTable but then it is displayed in a tabular format.
I want a simple format like:

[image: Data to be displayed as]

I dont want the exact tabular format.I am using **iTextSharp** dll.
Is it possible to display data in the above metioned format?

Any suggestions are welcome..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So when you say that you don't want exact tabular format are you talking about the borders? If so, I'd recommend using a `PdfPTable` and turning the borders off then. Cells in a `PdfPTable` are all based on the table's `DefaultCell`, so to turn the borders off for a table called `t` you'd do this:

```
t.DefaultCell.Border = 0;
```

Below is a full working WinForms app targetting iTextSharp 5.1.1.0 that does exactly that:

```
//PdfPTable Example
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //PDF file to output
            string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Output.pdf");

            //Create a basic stream to write to
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                //Create a new PDF document
                using (Document doc = new Document())
                {
                    //Bind a the document to the stream
                    using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                    {
                        //Open our PDF for writing
                        doc.Open();

                        //Insert a new page into our output PDF
                        doc.NewPage();

                        //Create a three column table
                        PdfPTable t = new PdfPTable(3);

                        //Remove the border from the table
                        t.DefaultCell.Border = 0;

                        //For the first row we some extra padding
                        t.DefaultCell.PaddingBottom = 10;
                        t.AddCell("ColumnA");
                        t.AddCell("ColumnB");
                        t.AddCell("ColumnC");

                        //Reset the padding for the remaining cells
                        t.DefaultCell.PaddingBottom = 0;
                        t.AddCell("Value1");
                        t.AddCell("Value1");
                        t.AddCell("Value1");

                        t.AddCell("Value2");
                        t.AddCell("Value2");
                        t.AddCell("Value2");

                        //Add the table to the document
                        doc.Add(t);

                        //Close our output PDF
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

If for some reason you don't want to do this with a `PdfPTable` you can *try* hacking it together with a `Paragraph` but unless alignment isn't important you are going to give yourself a headache. The sample below uses paragraphs and formats each "column" within the paragraph to be 20 characters each, padding spaces as necessary. **NOTE:** This is 20 characters of a variable-width font so things don't actually align. If you want that, either use the `PdfPTable` above or you are going to have to measure strings which is not fun.

```
//Paragraph Example
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //PDF file to output
            string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Output.pdf");

            //Create a basic stream to write to
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                //Create a new PDF document
                using (Document doc = new Document())
                {
                    //Bind a the document to the stream
                    using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                    {
                        //Open our PDF for writing
                        doc.Open();

                        //Insert a new page into our output PDF
                        doc.NewPage();

                        //Right-pad each "column" for a total of 20 characters
                        string FormatString = "{0,-20}{1,-20}{2,-20}";

                        //Add the first row
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph(String.Format(FormatString, "ColumnA", "ColumnB", "ColumnC")));

                        //Add a blank line
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph(""));

                        //Add the two data rows
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph(String.Format(FormatString, "Value1", "Value1", "Value1")));
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph(String.Format(FormatString, "Value2", "Value2", "Value2")));


                        //Close our output PDF
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PdfParagraph` class to render genreal text in PDF

Answer (score 0):

In iTextSharp dll, you just pass your data by creating table/tr/td structure in string like this :

```
string strData = string.Emrty;
strData = "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
strData += "<tr>";
strData += "<td>";
strData += "</td>";
strData += "</tr>";
strData += "</table>";
```

by creating table/tr/td structure of your data, just pass this variable data to pdf, then you will get your resulted output in pdf.